# Java android get one bitmap from imageView and TextView

Tags: java, android

I have in my view imageView and textView in linearLayout and I want to get a one bitmap from this two controls. I try do this :

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

But my application is crash and I see this :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

Comment: Because your view width and height will be MATCH_PARENT. And MATCH_PARENT value is -1. You can try getMeasuredWidth and Height instead of getLayoutParams.width / height

Answer (score 0):

```
if (v.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```